# Yocto: unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=neon' in using arm cross compiler on intel machine

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, intel, yocto

I am using arm cross compiler on Intel machine and facing below issue. Using yocto build system.

```
    | In file included from gpufiles.h:12:0,
    |                  from gpufiles.cpp:7:
    poky/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/arm-oemllib32-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oemllib32-linux-gnueabi/4.9.3/include/arm_neon.h:31:2: error: #error You must enable NEON instructions (e.g. -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon) to use arm_neon.h

|  #error You must enable NEON instructions (e.g. -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon) to use arm_neon.h
```

I have added below flags in makefile.am:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon
```

But I am seeing another issue here:

```
unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=neon'
```

Please help me to resolve this. Your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Which target architecture is this? Have you checked in the log that the cross-compiler really gets used (and not e.g. a host native one)?

Comment: This is for msm based arm architecture  and i am sure  that my cross-complier is getting called

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on which kind of compiler you are using and which version it is.
For GCC/ARM v7 compiler/ARM v8 compiler, there are some minor difference about the compiler option support.

Please refer to below URL for ARM compiler information:
https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/compilers